# Reading in more than one variable into $FILE

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell script which reads in the names of files stored in a directory and then matches these files in another directory. If the two match then an email is sent to the recipient.

This is what I have written so far

```
 OUTFILES=/remote/output

 cd $OUTFILES
for FILE in XML*.email
do
  RECIPIENT=`head -1 $FILE`
  ATTACHMENT=`head -2 $FILE | tail -1`

echo $RECIPIENT
echo $ATTACHMENT

ATTACHFILES=:/projects/scripts

  cd $ATTACHFILES
         for FILE in *.pdf do
            ATTACH=`ls -1 $FILE`

    if [ $ATTACHMENT=$ATTACH ]; then


        echo $ATTACH

    fi
done

uuencode $ATTACH $ATTACH | mail $RECIPIENT 2>&1
```

The script fails at this line

```
ATTACH=`ls -1 $FILE`
```

Is it because I am trying to read 2 $FILES in the same script

Thanks

Comment: I dint get this command `ATTACHFILES=:/projects/scripts`. 
There is a colon in the path and you're doing cd to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting spaces around the equal sign:

```
if [ $ATTACHMENT = $ATTACH ]; then
```

Furthermore you *really* should use double quotes in all your cases where you use a variable:

```
OUTFILES=/remote/output

cd "$OUTFILES"
for FILE in XML*.email
do
  RECIPIENT=`head -1 "$FILE"`
  ATTACHMENT=`head -2 "$FILE" | tail -1`

  echo "$RECIPIENT"
  echo "$ATTACHMENT"

  ATTACHFILES=:/projects/scripts

  cd "$ATTACHFILES"
  for FILE in *.pdf
  do
    ATTACH=`ls -1 "$FILE"`

    if [ "$ATTACHMENT" = "$ATTACH" ]
    then
      echo $ATTACH
    fi
  done
done  # I inserted this "done" because as indention shows this was missing.
uuencode "$ATTACH" "$ATTACH" | mail "$RECIPIENT" 2>&1
```